# How to run pytorch neural network as if it was in server

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, production-environment

I have a model like so that I've already trained

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F



transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(30),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 10, 3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(780, 70)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(70, 50)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x



net = Net()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('classifier.pth'))
net.eval()


test_img = Image.open('test.jpg')

processed_img = transform(test_img)

output = net(processed_img)
predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)

print(predicted)
```

When I run this, I get

```
File "XXX.py", line 26, in forward
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
  File "/Users/XXX/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/XXX/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x36 and 780x70)
```

I know it means the tensor shapes don't line up, but I didn't see this problem during training or testing with the data from the loaders.

So I guess my main question is how would I get this network working in a flask app api endpoint for example. How should I process the image so that the network works, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Think I found the issue. I assumed transform.Resize made the image into a square. It doesn't.